# Icon checked navigation bar android

Tags: android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

[image: Checked Icon]
[image: Colors]
[image: Wrong Checked Icon]

```
package com.example.inventoryinsight;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Objects.requireNonNull(this.getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.menu_home); -->EDIT TO ADD THE SELECTED ITEM DEFAULT
    }

    //Method for the navigation bar screen select
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        int itemId = item.getItemId();

        //Will navigate to correct activity based on selected destination
        if (itemId == R.id.menu_add) {
            fragment = new AddFragment();
        } else if (itemId == R.id.menu_remove) {
            fragment = new RemoveFragment();
        } else if (itemId == R.id.menu_home) {
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
        } else if (itemId == R.id.menu_search) {
            fragment = new SearchFragment();
        } else if (itemId == R.id.menu_settings) {
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        }
        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }

    //Used to load the selected fragment
    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I am working to get the active icon to change color. It works when I pick each one, the only issue is that I want the Home icon to be the active one when I launch the app. Right now, the add icon is the active one when the app launches. Is there a way to do this within the design or does it need to be down programmatically?

Comment: try this line after setting your listener on navigation: navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.menu_home);

Comment: And please next time copy your code inside code tags while asking questions. That way we can test solutions for your problem, this way no one will retype your code to test it. Use images just to show layouts or something, there are code brackets, and just copy code inside them.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I also moved the code into a code tag, sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, happy coding!